# Python list "not defined", but I am able to print the results

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I have a list `time_end_list` created outside of my for loop.  I have a few functions inside the for loop and append to the list while in the loop.  I then can successfully print `time_end_list` but when I try to use it, I get the error `NameError: name 'time_end_list' is not defined`.

I have been going round and round and I am sure it is simple, but I seem to be missing it.

Thank you.

**CODE**

```
Class AddBuyerScheduleForm(FlaskForm):
    string_of_times = [
        '09:00AM\r\n09:30AM\r\n10:00AM\r\n10:30AM\r\n11:00AM\r\n11:30AM\r\n\
            12:00PM\r\n12:30PM\r\n01:00PM\r\n01:30PM\r\n02:00PM\r\n02:30PM\r\n\
                03:00PM\r\n03:30PM\r\n04:00PM\r\n05:00PM'
    ]
    # This is the events increment
    increment = 15
    list_of_times = string_of_times[0].split()
    time_end_list = []
    for t in list_of_times:
        f = datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M%p') + timedelta(minutes=increment)
        time_end_list.append(f.strftime('%H:%M%p'))
    print(f'The time list is {time_end_list}')
    # create a list of value/description tuples
    files = [(x, y) for x in list_of_times for y in time_end_list]
    times = MultiCheckBoxForm('Label', choices=files)
```

**Error**

```
The time list is ['09:15AM', '09:45AM', '10:15AM', '10:45AM', '11:15AM', '11:45AM', '12:15PM', '12:45PM', '01:15AM', '01:45AM', '02:15AM', '02:45AM', '03:15AM', '03:45AM', '04:15AM', '05:15AM']
File "/Users/administrator/Documents/python/business_connect_live/myproject/buyers/forms.py", line 136, in <listcomp>
    files = [(x, y) for x in list_of_times for y in time_end_list]
NameError: name 'time_end_list' is not defined
```

Comment: Try `files = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(list_of_times, time_end_list)]`

Comment: This seems to have worked.  I will have to read up on `zip`.  Thank you.